# what does this error message mean in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run this code and I get the error message that you can see. Why?

```
fit=np.polyfit(na[0],na[1],1)
fit_fn=np.poly1d(fit)
plt.plot(na[0],na[1],'yo',na[0],fit_fn(na[0]),'--k')
plt.title("LINEAR REGRESSION OF ENERGY/EFFICIENCY OF ONE TYPE DETECTOR")
plt.xlabel("ENERGY")
plt.ylabel("EFFICIENCY")

plt.show(block=False)
```

> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:590:
>   FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison   if
>   self._edgecolors == str('face'):

Comment: Where are you declaring `na`?

Comment: This is to do with an upgrade to `numpy v1.10`. See [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5209/). This should go away if you upgrade to `matplotlib v1.5.0`. For now I think you can safely ignore it.